# Excel convert digits into respective words

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Click to view Image]

I would like to convert the number of digits in excel into respective words as shown in the picture above. How can I achieve this functionality in an excel sheet? Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In **Formulas > Name Manager**, define a named array containing the names of the digits as text:
   [image]
2. Select the range B2:E3. Enter the formula `=INDEX(DigitsToWords,MID(RIGHT("0000"&VALUETOTEXT($A2),4),COLUMN()-1,1)+1)`, using Ctrl+Enter to apply it to all cells in the range. You will need to adjust this if you want to accommodate larger, negative or non-integer numbers.

Result:
[image]